# How to stream video from videogame to another computer in realtime?

Tags: c#, encoding, streaming, capture

I just started coding an application, my idea is to create something like StreamMyGame but for personal use, there is already a project called Single Player Game Transmiter that achieves some of this (http://sourceforge.net/projects/spgt/files/).

So far I'm not encoding nor streaming, I'm just capturing video and displaying it in my app window.

So how could I handle encoding/streaming? I was thinking an UDP stream of raw JPEGs would be the easiest path but I'm not sure.

Also how could I optimize what I have so far? It works fine for video playback but when capturing game windows it doesn't seem as snappy as the original video, I think it might be due to the fact that it's running in the background. That leads me to another question, how can I capture the Window with the specified title instead of the active Window?

https://github.com/fr500/desktop_streamer

**EDIT**:

Some tests with the current Capture Method:

**Video Player Capture (960x720p)**

```
starting benchmark
================================================
looking for window: test.mp4
looking for window: test.mp4
looking for window: test.mp4
looking for window: test.mp4
looking for window: test.mp4
================================================
starting single thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 19480 milliseconds
Frame Time: 32 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting single thread capture and save as bmp test

Time Elapsed: 19768 milliseconds
Frame Time: 32 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting single thread capture and save as jpg test

Time Elapsed: 28593 milliseconds
Frame Time: 47 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 20
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting dual thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 19515 milliseconds
Frame Time: 32 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting quad thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 19481 milliseconds
Frame Time: 32 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds
```

**Crysis 2 Capture (1024x768p)**

```
starting benchmark
================================================
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
looking for window: Crysis 2 (TM)
================================================
starting single thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 20003 milliseconds
Frame Time: 33 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 29
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting single thread capture and save as bmp test

Time Elapsed: 20105 milliseconds
Frame Time: 33 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 29
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting single thread capture and save as jpg test

Time Elapsed: 17353 milliseconds
Frame Time: 28 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 34
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting dual thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 19991 milliseconds
Frame Time: 33 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds

starting quad thread capture only test

Time Elapsed: 19983 milliseconds
Frame Time: 33 milliseconds
Rough FPS: 30
Sleeping 2 seconds
```

Saving image to BMP doesn't really add any overhead but saving as JPG does which gives me an idea of the overhead encoding to video could have. Still the biggest issue is getting the frames themselves it's too slow as it is now, **it can't keep up and as a result some frames are missing**. If frames could be captured at 60+ fps the encoding + streaming delay could be really manageable for single player games.

I will try a DX hook approach to get the frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if performance/quality issues are effect of running in the background, however I'll try to answer your question.

**Capturing window by its name**

I suppose you can try to use `FindWindow` function instead of `GetForegroundWindow` that is used in the application. It allows you to get handle to a window by its title. In order to do this (in the desktop_streamer project you've posted a link to), go to the `ScreenCapture` class and:

- change

  ```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
  ```

  to

  ```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
  ```
- in `Capture` method change the line

  ```
  var foregroundWindowsHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
  ```

  to

  ```
  var foregroundWindowsHandle = FindWindow(null, "mywindowName");
  ```

I haven't tested this, so if you have any issues with running the code, let me know, so we can look for a solution.

For more information about `FindWindow` function, take a look here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow.

**Performance and images quality**

When talking about performance, you may want to try measure network speed and latency in real time and then use those information to adjust images quality (compression level and resolution) appropriately. This can make the transmitted image pixelated from time to time, but should decrease effect of laggy gameplay.

You may also want to take a look at this page giving some performance comparison of two of the screen capturing methods: http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/04/fastest-screen-capture-using-c-vista-vs-win7/. It may help you improve te performance of screen capturing process, but as you can see, frame rates achieved are still too low to provide high quality gaming experience.

Comment: Maybe I'm measuring wrong but I get 16ms frametimes (before drawing the image)

Comment: Well I tried your code and it helps capturing even if game window is in the background, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you :). Times measured depend on a specific machine where measurements are performed. I haven't noticed that post I linked to was written in 2009, so your machine can be noticeably faster than the one used by the author of the article. If this answers your question, please mark it as answer, if not, tell me what else you want like to ask about :).

Comment: Now I need to encode the frames into a video, by my measurements I get 60ms from  the moment I request the capture to the moment the frame has been saved to disk that equates to roughly 60fps so it should be workable I guess. I'll be trying StreamMyGame and SPGTS to see if those seem smooth

Comment: Well I'm still missing the encoding/streaming part if you have any ideas for that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I wonder if you saved each image on disk in your tests. Try capturing images without saving them on disk to see how fast the capturing process itself can be. Saving files on disk can slow it down significantly. In order to encode the images to a video, you can try using FFMPEG. Take a look at this to get started: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-June/007560.html.

Comment: I did both as you can see in the updated question. Saving doesn't have a big overhead. Thanks I'll check that link.

Comment: Ah, I haven't noticed that :P. However, it's interesting that for the second set of measurements, capturing frames without saving them took more time than capturing and saving them as JPGs. Make sure each of the tests is performed in similar conditions and that you capture enough frames to minimize influence of external factors (i.e. cpu used by another processes).

Comment: Yes the crysis benchmark was weird tbh but otherwise it was mostly consistent, also when I tried using many threads I saw no difference whatsoever but I'm a noob so I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Maybe the processor was busy with another process and that's why the results are like this. Let me know when you check the method using DX.

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I build a golang project called ScreenStreamer, is a tool to stream current active window (Linux's or Windows's) to other device, like phone or another PC, as MJPEG, it's very realtime(delay < 100ms)

the project link: https://github.com/fiefdx/ScreenStreamer